# 3 sets of wire going to fixture!

Tags: electrical, light

I have 3 sets of wire going into a light fixture, one set from the switch,one set going to the next light, and one going to another light. Hooked up at the switch is white wires all connected together with a wire nut, both black wires on the terminal screws. How would I hook up a fixture? Would I just screw the white wires together and to the fixture white wire, and the same with the black?

Comment: The new fixture will also be controlled by that switch.  If that is what you want, go for it.  Does not matter which light fixture you use for the connection point, does not need to be the same one.

Comment: Wire up your new fixture in the *exact same way* as your old fixture was wired. Presumably the old one worked in the past... ? No need to get creative here.

Comment: Turn off the power at the breaker. Open up the switch at the wall, pull the switch out _without removing any wires_, take a picture of the wiring. Open up the ceiling box, pull out whatever is there _without removing any wires_, take a picture of what's there. [Edit] your question to include these pictures so that we can see what you see.

Comment: 3 sets of wires. "Both" black wires. There's a black wire unaccounted for.  Pictures definitely required.